# Ext Js 6.2, How to automatically expand East panel when West panel is fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using Ext Js v6.2 Grid, In my application,
I have two Panel WestRegion and EastRegion. If I close Westregion panel, **EastRegion panel should open automatically**, vice-versa, If I close EastRegion panel, **Westregion panel should open automatically**, I've tried with Jquery because I'm newbie to Ext Js, Is there any option available with Ext Js, Here's my code:

```
  $('.WestRegion').on('click', function () {
    $('.EastRegion').click();
  });


 $('.EastRegion').on('click', function () {
    $('.WestRegion').click();
 });
```

[fiddlelink](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25r9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first: You should always search the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/index.html).

Add an itemId to each panel, like that: `itemId: 'westpanel'` and `itemId: 'eastpanel'`. Then you can get access to each panel if you need.

Now you should add [listeners](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-listeners) to your panels (example west):

```
listeners: {
  expand: function() {
    this.up('panel')
    .getComponent('eastpanel')
    .setCollapsed(false);
  }
}
```